# PHP Curl with flag for username/password

Tags: php, curl

Im trying to make a simple curl request to the desk.com api using PHP but having trouble getting a response. Below is their documentation.

```
$ curl https://yoursite.desk.com/api/v2/cases/:id \
-u email:password \
-H 'Accept: application/json'
```

Here is my PHP to try and accomplish the above

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://url.desk.com/api/v2/cases -u email:password");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 'Accept: application/json');

$output = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($output);

curl_close($ch);
```

Ive barely used curl before so any help as to why I'm not getting a response would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried sending basic authorization?

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://url.desk.com/api/v2/cases");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 'Accept: application/json');
```

You also won't need the '-u' in your url, that is meant for command line curl.

Additionally, You'll need to replace ':id' with the ID of the case for the above to return a specific case. For example:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://url.desk.com/api/v2/cases/1");
```

Comment: I hadn't, like i said this is pretty new to me but that worked a treat. Many thanks.

Comment: No worries, we were all there once.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead, be sure to define/replace $email and $password

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://url.desk.com/api/v2/cases");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "{$email}:{$password}");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 'Accept: application/json');

$output = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($output);

curl_close($ch);
```